# What is the best choice in this case, 'has taken' vs. 'has been taking'?

Tags: perfect-continuous

Consider:

> Jessy **has taken or has been taking** driving lessons and next week she is going to take the driving test

I think *has been taking* can make it as taking driving lessons has been an ongoing action if you want to emphasize the continuity of the action.

But I think *has taken* could also make it if you want to emphasize the result. She probably is not taking driving lessons until she has the result of the test. If she passes it, no more lessons will be needed, and the action will be completed.

Comment: Neither is wrong, but **has been taking** is probably more natural in this context.

Answer (score 1):

You have the general idea.

**Has taken** heavily implies that she is done taking lessons.

**Has been taking** implies that it is still ongoing (but will probably stop if she passes the test)

Answer (score 0):

She has been taking driving lessons until very recently and she still has to take her her test, so present perfect continuous is correct. If you want to say how many lessons she has taken so far, use the present perfect simple: "she has taken 35 lessons so far".